# Modify div size with no access to html

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to edit some background on a page. I don't have access to the html file, only .css and .js. The page has a default theme that won't expand the background on the whole screen (bottom) because of the  structure. I managed to swap the default background .png with an animated gradient through css but now I need to change the div. Tried with the @import url at the very top of the css file to call an external css but it won't work. Are there any ways to override the html structure? thank you

- Forgot to say that I don't have access to the default template's css either. The service keeps everything on the server and once I installed the template in the local folder (the whole thing works with dropbox) I found an additional .css and .js in which I can add other code, though they come basically blank. What I need to do is to override the template's div structure from one of those 2 files. Using DevTools i found the name of the template div class and I guess I can download the relative .css. Still don't know how to override it... I'm not too familiar with coding in general...

Comment: change the css background property for the div

Comment: You can add class for needed div and specify this class in css file. Or you can insert inline style with devTools

Comment: You can do anything with js, if you can manage to run something onload.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear with what you're trying to do. But you can always use Javascript DOM manipulation functions.

Check out this link for that: http://callmenick.com/post/basics-javascript-dom-manipulation.

You can also use [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) which provides better API.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in some class definition or in a stylesheet file then use selector with high [`Specificity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to get your definition on high priority

```css
.oldclass{
  width:328px;
  height:328px;
  background-image:url('http://via.placeholder.com/328x328');
}
/*Your New definition*/
div.oldclass{
  background-image:url('http://via.placeholder.com/328x328');
}
```

```html
<div class="oldclass">
</div>
```

If it is in inline style, then use `!important` tag

```css
.oldclass{
  width:328px;
  height:328px
}
/*Your New definition*/
div.oldclass{
  background-image:url('http://via.placeholder.com/328x328') !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="oldclass" style="background-image:url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fca24c2acab4d63343d4608ce256dcec?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');">
</div>
```

Comment: Forgot to say that I don't have access to the default template's css either. The service keeps everything on the server and once I installed the template in the local folder (the whole thing works with dropbox) I found an additional .css and .js in which I can add other code, though they come basically blank. What I need to do is to override the template's div structure from one of those 2 files. Using DevTools i found the name of the template div class and I guess I can download the relative .css. Still don't know how to override it... I'm not too familiar with coding in general...